# Reading xml from an URL python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am reading an XML file from a URL, but when I try to locate elements in it, it doesn't work and finds nothing.

```
url = "https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/media/sitemap_en.xml"
response = requests.get(url)
root = ET.fromstring(response.content)

for elm in root.findall('.//loc'):
    print(elm)
```

here is the XML I am working with: https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/media/sitemap_en.xml
how to parse this XML from this URL and locate all loc tags or elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<loc>` element is inside namespace `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9`:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


url = "https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/media/sitemap_en.xml"
response = requests.get(url)
root = ET.fromstring(response.content)

for elm in root.findall(".//{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}loc"):
    print(elm.text)
```

Prints:

```
...
https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/magpul-moe-grip-sl-stock-midnight-marshland-furniture-set
https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/magpul-moe-grip-sl-s-stock-midnight-marshland-furniture-set
https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/magpul-moe-grip-prs-gen3-stock-midnight-marshland-furniture-set
https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/battle-rope-2pt0-357-38-cal-9mm-pistol
https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/battle-2pt0-rope-22-223-cal-pistol-rifle
```

Comment: hey man i have a follow up a question, would appreciate it if you could help on this one too. i edited the question

Comment: @Hamza Don't edit the question with new followup question - it creates lots of confusion. Revert it back, post new question here on SO. I'll look at it.

Comment: oh Ok, will do.